# Multiple persistent sessions to different domains

Tags: php, session-cookies, cross-site

I have a html-based WebApp (written in php) accessed via browser which I want to extend to include (showing) data from other sites running the same app. I thought I could easily use ajax to get the html-formatted data and paste it into the origin site. But each http request to the other domain opens a new session on the target host (eg at least Firefox does so).

What I think I could do is, to store the remote sessions on client side (eg LocalStorage or SessionStorage) and send it as header with the ajax call. But this would require to store all the (user-authenticated) session-ids at client side and probably this is very unsecure!?

Does anyone have a better suggestion or give me some hints to be aware of when doing so.

Comment: really? no one??